# pass a textbox text as a parameter to popup control extender dynamic context key

Tags: asp.net, ajax, popup

I have a date text box where  date is selected by the user.I want to pass this value to the popup control extenders DynamicContextKey value so that i can use that value to retrieve values from the database to populate in the popup.

How can pass this value.below is my popup control extender.

```
<asp:PopupControlExtender ID="img_magnify_PopupControlExtender" runat="server" 
                    DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" Position ="Bottom" 
                    TargetControlID="img_magnify" PopupControlID="panel1" DynamicServiceMethod = "GetRegionalDataSubmissionStatus" DynamicContextKey = '<%# TXT_DATE.TEXT %>' >
                </asp:PopupControlExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a label in a panel which you want to popup, and bind its text with the required data (date in your case)?